# MySQL: Get rows with creation date string newer than given date string

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, string-comparison

I am trying to create a prepared statement with following code:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 
    STR_CMP(creationDate, $startingDate) = 1 ORDER BY creationDate DESC ");
```

I have also tried this:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 
    (creationDate > $startingDate) = 1 ORDER BY creationDate DESC ");
```

But I am getting null `$statement`. My goal is to get rows which it's creatrion date is newer than given date string. My `creationDate` column is stored as string.

I have logged my query string and it look like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (creationDate > 05.02.2015 14:08:31) = 1 ORDER BY creationDate DESC
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is creationDate stored as string? Not dateTime?

Comment: Does it matter? Ididn't need it as DateTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by trying my query string in my `phpMyAdmin` sql query section of my database. And I have relized when I build my query like this:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 
    (creationDate > $startingDate) = 1 ORDER BY creationDate DESC ");
```

It becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (creationDate > 05.02.2015 14:08:31) = 1 
    ORDER BY creationDate DESC
```

and `MySql` gives error for `05.02.2015 14:08:31`

So I have prepared my statement like this:

```
$queryString = 'SELECT * FROM arendi_ideas WHERE (creationDate > "'.$startingDate.'") = 1 ORDER BY creationDate DESC';
$this->logger->debug("GetIdeasNewerThan: Query string = $queryString");
$this->statement = $this->db->prepare($queryString);
```

and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to compare date to date.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 

DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(creationDate, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'),'%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')

> '.$startingDate.'  ORDER BY creationDate DESC
```

Tips

2) Store date in DB as date not string

3) Your date string seems to invalid?
Why not YYYYMMDD.

`ORDER BY creationDate DESC` may implict unexpected reulsts